# Fail to detect edges using original BSDS model

Tags: opencv

I'm unable to detect edges using structured forest training's **original** BSDS model (https://github.com/pdollar/edges/blob/master/models/forest/modelBsds.mat). To convert from `.mat` to `.yml`, I use this script https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/tutorials/scripts/modelConvert.m with the command `modelConvert(model, "model.yml")`, as advised [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d59/tutorial_ximgproc_training.html#gsc.tab=0). However, when I run edge detection with the converted model, I get this:

[image]

when the input image is:

[image]

That said, [this model](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/blob/master/testdata/cv/ximgproc/model.yml.gz) works though. Anyone know why the original `.mat` model doesn't work? Here's my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('./kermit.jpg')

edgedetector = cv2.ximgproc.createStructuredEdgeDetection('./model.yml')

src = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

edges = edgedetector.detectEdges(np.float32(src) / 255.0)

cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
```

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1282
http://answers.opencv.org/question/72962/trained-model-for-opencv-structured-edge-detection/?answer=95989#post-id-95989

The same issue is described here, have a look.